# Python read file with text separed with ;

Tags: python, file

I'd like to read a file with some txt and put into variables

The file env.txt is like this:

```
15;TEXT;20
20;TEXT2;29
```

In python the variables should be like this:

```
firstID = 10
name = TEXT
secondID = 20
```

I searched on internet and figured out a way to read it line by line, but I need to read each item between ;

Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you tired so far? Show us your code!

Comment: You have a few options. Using `split` on the lines, using the csv reader with semicolon as the separator, rolling your own splitter, probably others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('env.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
data = [row.split(';') for row in text.split('\n')[:-1]]
for firstID, name, secondID in data:
    print(f'firstID: {firstID}')
    print(f'name: {name}')
    print(f'secondID: {secondID}')
```

You could use this code snippet for that

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use split(";") to split each line.